# Calculate only the first dimension elements in a two dimension array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimension array that stores coordinates (xy) `int arr[3][3]`. How do I do calculations to only one of the dimensions in the array?

If I am interested in **the average of the x coordinates** I would type:

`float sumX = (float) arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[3] / 3.0f;`

When I do this I get the error `invalid cast from type 'int*' to type 'float'`. How can I not be allowed to do this?

Comment: It should be `arr[0][0] + arr[0][1] + ....`

Comment: Also the expression that you are writing down for the sum is wrong. Your `(float)` only applies to the first term and you should have paranthesis around the sum.

Comment: Note that arr[3] is beyond your array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only the first element of each row contains the x-ordinate, you should do something like this -

```
float sumX = (arr[0][0] + arr[1][0] + arr[2][0]) / 3.0f;
```

`arr[0][0]` gives you the value stored in the first element of the first row in your array, `arr[1][0]` gives you the value stored in the first element of the second row in your array, and so on. Change the above expression according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
float sumX = (float) (arr[0][0] + arr[1][0] + arr[2][0]) / 3.0f;
```

You need brackets to group what gets operated on and you need to specify a single value rather than a row.

Comment: is there a need to cast? dividing a number with decimal number will result in decimal value

Comment: In my professional environment we try to avoid implicit casts for a couple of reasons: 1) Clarity if there is an explicit cast there is no doubt what you are looking at & 2) MISRA rules against it because _some_ implicit casts can cause problems so if you have none ....

Comment: But when typing `arr[0][0] + arr[1][0]...` it will calculate x + y. I only want to calculate x and ignore y.

Comment: Since arr is type int[3][3] arr[0] is type int[3] but arr[0][0] is type int and is the first element of the first row.  I and others have assumed that the second 3 is for [x,y,z] if it is not you need to clarify how your data is organised. You may need to use [0][0], [0][1], [0][2].

Comment: @user3005287 I think you need to reconsider what you're trying to achieve here. You talk about two-dimensional arrays and x and y coordinates. The two-dimensionality of the array has nothing to do with the two dimensions x and y in a 2d plane. In the array, the first dimension is the point or row index, the second dimension is the coordinate _index_, i.e. 0 for x and 1 for y. There's no z in your case, so 2 is unused.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, @Steve. Let's assume that this is the data in the array:

x = 2

x2 = 5

x3 = 10

y = 3

y2 = 4

y3 = 6

If I want to calculate the sum of all the x integers and I type `arr[0][0] + arr[1][0] + arr[2][0]` the sum will be 15 because the calculation will be `x + y` `x2 + y` `x3 + y`. Right?

Comment: How is the data arranged? [[2, 5, 10],[3, 4, 6],[0,0,0]] or [[2,3,0],[5,4,0],[10,6,0]] each arr[n][m] accesses a SINGE value.

Answer (score -1):

Address will be returned in this case

```
float sumX = (float) arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[3] / 3.0f;
```

To return the value use the indirection operator

```
float sumX = (float) ( *arr[0] + *arr[1] + *arr[3] )/ 3.0f;
```

Comment: **BRACKETS** are needed!

Comment: where the brackets are needed

Comment: 1/3 of what is at address arr[3] plus what is at arr[1], etc.